# ftp doesn't download the file properly in java?

Tags: java, ftp, connection

When i download file with following code it just write the file to destination on local but file size are all zero. **Can anybody say Why this happen and how to fix it?**

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFile;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class FtpDownload {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    String filename = "config.zip";
    try {
        client.connect("ftpsrv");
        client.login("user", "user");

        for (FTPFile file : client.listFiles()) {
            filename = "C:\\tmp\\user\\" + file.getName();
            if (file.isFile()) {
                fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
                client.retrieveFile(filename, fos);
                System.out.println(file.getName());
            } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("directory: " + file.getName());
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fos != null) {
                fos.close();
            }
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the Java Swing library? Why the Swing tag?

Comment: Your stream handling is a nightmare, you only close the last FileOutputStream.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

after searching in the Apache documentation i come to conclusion that BINARY_FILE_TYPE is not yet settled. i have add following code and everything is OK. thanks to all of you that did help.

```
try {
    client.connect(ftpServer);
    client.login(username, password);
    // following line fixed my zip file corruption issue.
    client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Comment: This is a great help. This fixes the downloaded file problem, "the archived file is incomplete". Thank you so much!

Comment: This fixed some corrupt gzipped (.gz) files I was getting from an FTP request, thanks.

Comment: By the way, the last line should be :  
**client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);**

Answer (score 4):

You're using the local path variable to point to the remote file:

```
filename = "C:\\tmp\\user\\" + file.getName();
...
client.retrieveFile(filename, fos);
```

You want to point to the remote file, not the local destination, like this:

```
client.retrieveFile(file.getName(), fos);
```

Also, make sure you close your `fos` stream after reading each file, rather than right at the end. You can use `IOUtils.closeQuietly(fos);` for this if you get the [commons.io](http://commons.apache.org/io/) library, which avoids the nested try-catch blocks.

You should also use **BINARY** file type and **BLOCK** transfer mode for transferring zip files:

```
client.setFileTransferMode(FTPClient.BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE);
client.setFileType(FTPClient.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

Comment: after download when i open the file i get following error:**Error: unrecoverable Zip file read error.** this happen only with zip file.when i download .csv file it is ok.

Comment: That sounds like a different problem altogether. Can you download and open the zip file manually? It sounds like the config.zip file on the server is corrupted.

Comment: Looking down the page it looks like you beat me to this @itro, but I updated my answer anyway for completeness.

Comment: The `BLOCK_TRANSFER_MODE ` saved me here, I was getting a `Central Directory Entry signature not found` error

Answer (score 1):

try closing the stream on every iteration in the loop

```
fos.close();
```

Your code is not doing it correctly because you have a for loop that creates new stream every iteration but only close the last one

Comment: after download when i open the file i get following error:´Error: unrecoverable Zip file read error.´